# Prestashop 1.6.1.14 - Variables Not Replaced in Shipped Email Set

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have created an override on AdminOrderController.php. I am using the variables {$followup} and {$code_traking} and placed in Shipped.html.

Unfortunately, I am baffled as to why it is only working for single order status change. When I tried to update as bulk, both {$followup} and {$code_traking} are not replaced in the email.

{$firstname}, {$lastname} and {$id_order} are generating in the emails as per norm.

Below are the codes.

```
        } elseif (Tools::isSubmit('sendStateEmail') && Tools::getValue('sendStateEmail') > 0 && Tools::getValue('id_order') > 0) {
        if ($this->tabAccess['edit'] === '1') {
            $order_state = new OrderState((int)Tools::getValue('sendStateEmail'));

            if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order_state)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while loading order status.');
            } else {
                $history = new OrderHistory((int)Tools::getValue('id_order_history'));

                $carrier = new Carrier($order->id_carrier, $order->id_lang);
                $templateVars = array();
                $templateVars = array(
                    '{followup}' => str_replace('@', $order->shipping_number, $carrier->url),
                    '{url_traking}' => $carrier->url,
                    '{shipping_number}' => $order->shipping_number,
                    '{code_traking}' => $order->shipping_number
                );

                if ($history->sendEmail($order, $templateVars)) {
                    Tools::redirectAdmin(self::$currentIndex.'&id_order='.$order->id.'&vieworder&conf=10&token='.$this->token);
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while sending the e-mail to the customer.');
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You do not have permission to edit this.');
        }
```

I have tried adding the following codes below to the override but it is still not displaying. I have cleared cache.

```
      public function processBulkUpdateOrderStatus()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitUpdateOrderStatus')
        && ($id_order_state = (int)Tools::getValue('id_order_state'))) {
        if ($this->tabAccess['edit'] !== '1') {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You do not have permission to edit this.');
        } else {
            $order_state = new OrderState($id_order_state);

            if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order_state)) {
                $this->errors[] = sprintf(Tools::displayError('Order status #%d cannot be loaded'), $id_order_state);
            } else {
                foreach (Tools::getValue('orderBox') as $id_order) {
                    $order = new Order((int)$id_order);
                    if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order)) {
                        $this->errors[] = sprintf(Tools::displayError('Order #%d cannot be loaded'), $id_order);
                    } else {
                        $current_order_state = $order->getCurrentOrderState();
                        if ($current_order_state->id == $order_state->id) {
                            $this->errors[] = $this->displayWarning(sprintf('Order #%d has already been assigned this status.', $id_order));
                        } else {
                            $history = new OrderHistory();
                            $history->id_order = $order->id;
                            $history->id_employee = (int)$this->context->employee->id;

                            $use_existings_payment = !$order->hasInvoice();
                            $history->changeIdOrderState((int)$order_state->id, $order, $use_existings_payment);

                            $carrier = new Carrier($order->id_carrier, $order->id_lang);
                            $templateVars = array();
                            if ($history->id_order_state == Configuration::get('PS_OS_SHIPPING') && $order->shipping_number) {
                               //$templateVars = array('{followup}' => str_replace('@', $order->shipping_number, $carrier->url));
                               $templateVars = array(
                                '{followup}' => str_replace('@', $order->shipping_number, $carrier->url),
                                '{url_traking}' => $carrier->url,
                                '{shipping_number}' => $order->shipping_number,
                                '{code_traking}' => $order->shipping_number
                            );
                            }

                            if ($history->addWithemail(true, $templateVars)) {
                                if (Configuration::get('PS_ADVANCED_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')) {
                                    foreach ($order->getProducts() as $product) {
                                        if (StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['product_id'])) {
                                            StockAvailable::synchronize($product['product_id'], (int)$product['id_shop']);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                $this->errors[] = sprintf(Tools::displayError('Cannot change status for order #%d.'), $id_order);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!count($this->errors)) {
            Tools::redirectAdmin(self::$currentIndex.'&conf=4&token='.$this->token);
        }
    }
}

public function renderList()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitBulkupdateOrderStatus'.$this->table)) {
        if (Tools::getIsset('cancel')) {
            Tools::redirectAdmin(self::$currentIndex.'&token='.$this->token);
        }

        $this->tpl_list_vars['updateOrderStatus_mode'] = true;
        $this->tpl_list_vars['order_statuses'] = $this->statuses_array;
        $this->tpl_list_vars['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this->tpl_list_vars['POST'] = $_POST;
    }

    return parent::renderList();
}
```

Is there any other areas I need to edit to get this working for bulk order status change? I do not find it feasible from my end to update every single order, one by one as it is too time consuming. :(

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the email template also. And have you deleted the cache/class_index.php file after adding the override or was the override install in a module installation?

Comment: I have cleared class_index.php but still the variables are not showing for bulk orders status change.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override [processBulkUpdateOrderStatus()](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php#L380) method as well.

But if you used a module and a proper hook [actionGetExtraMailTemplateVars](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Mail.php#L344) you wouldn't have these problems and you wouldn't need overrides.

Module hook would be something like this:

```
public function hookActionGetExtraMailTemplateVars($params)
{
    // Don't do anything if email template is not for shipped status
    if ($params['template'] != 'shipped') {
        return null;
    }

    // Read order ID from template vars that was set by OrderHistory class
    $orderID = $params['template_vars']['{id_order}'];
    $order = new Order((int)$orderID);
    $carrier = new Carrier($order->id_carrier, $order->id_lang);

    /* 
       Merge extra_template_vars because some other modules might already set
       their custom email variables otherwise they would be lost if you just set
       it with your own data
    */
    $params['extra_template_vars'] = array_merge(
                 $params['extra_template_vars'], 
                 array(
                    '{followup}' => str_replace('@', $order->shipping_number, $carrier->url),
                    '{url_traking}' => $carrier->url,
                    '{shipping_number}' => $order->shipping_number,
                    '{code_traking}' => $order->shipping_number
                ));
}
```

Comment: I have tried overriding but it is still not showing the 2 variables. But can I just check, even if I did not override, the default will show {followup} value as it has been assigned in processBulkUpdateOrderStatus(), right? (Line 411)

Comment: @MuhammadFakhrinBinUmar Yes that value will show. Is your overriden method executing at all? Try to die() somewhere inside it to see if it's working. Otherwise you might need to delete `cache/class_index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I thank @TheDrot for showing guiding me towards the solution. There is an importance to overriding AdminOrdersController.php. We need to include processBulkOrderStatus() and I have the following codes removed to make bulk status order change in proper with additional variables. Without removing the condition below, it will be futile.

```
//remove the condition below
if ($history->id_order_state == Configuration::get('PS_OS_SHIPPING') && 
$order->shipping_number) {
//leave the rest of the codes intact
}
```

Thank you.